# Rails - Change HTML based on number of records remainder 3

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, materialize

I am writing a basic Rails application to keep track of homework (Basically just a database interface). I am using the grid system from the Materialize CSS framework (the same as Bootstrap, 12 columns). When I collect records from the database (pieces of homework) I want to display them so that it will try to split each row into 3 divs of 4 columns, if there are only two records on the last row then it should split them into two divs of 6 columns and if there is only one record on the last row then it should show it as one div of 12 columns.

Here is my attempt:

```
<% count = 1 %>
<% @homeworks.each do |homework| %>
  <% if @homeworks.length - count > 0 then %>
    <div class="col s12 m4">
    <% count = count + 1 %>
  <% elsif @homeworks.length - count == 1 then %>
    <div class="col s12 m6">
  <% else %>
    <div class="col s12 m12">
  <% end %>
    <a href="<%= homework_path(homework) %>">
      <div class="card-panel hoverable">
        <center><h5 class="cutoff"><%= homework.title %></h5></center><br>
        <%= truncate(homework.content, :length => 17, :separator => ' ') %>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

This worked fine for 5 records:

[image: Screenshot]

However, with 6 records I get this result:

[image: Screenshot]

Can anybody point me in the right direction? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't entirely understand your logic with the `count` variable, but that's not how I'd approach the problem regardless - there's a much simpler and cleaner way: Use [`Enumberable#each_slice`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_slice).

Your code will look something along the lines of:

```
<% @homeworks.each_slice(3) do |homeworks_row| %>
  <% if homeworks_row.length == 3 %>
    <% width_class = "m4" %>
  <% elsif homeworks_row.length == 2 %>
    <% width_class = "m6" %>
  <% else %>
    <% width_class = "m12" %>
  <% end %>

  <% homeworks_row.each do |homework| %>
    <div class="col s12 <%= width_class %>">
      <a href="<%= homework_path(homework) %>">
        <div class="card-panel hoverable">
          <center><h5 class="cutoff"><%= homework.title %></h5></center><br>
          <%= truncate(homework.content, :length => 17, :separator => ' ') %>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Each `homeworks_row` will contain either 1, 2 or 3 `homework`s - meaning you can simply choose the column width, based on the length of the row.

You may also want to improve this code by wrapping that `if` statement into a helper method, i.e. your template will include the line:

```
<div class="col s12 <%= width_class(homework_row.length) %>">
```

...but I'll leave this here as one block of code for simplicity.